# Search id by text and foreign key in Yii framework

Tags: php, search, yii2

I have form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'occurrence')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'probability')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

First input is a foreign key where table have names.

I don't know how to do If I type "aaa" get id foreign key.
Normally I use array helper and dropDownlist, but I can't here because first table have 400000 record.
I don't know how to do?
How to search in input form and return id in this input.
I'm using Yii 2 framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, using a dropdown list for all 400K elements would be a disaster. What you should use is one of many enhanced select controls:

- [Select2](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2)
- [Selectize](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-selectize-widget)
- [Chosen](https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-chosen-select)
- [Typeahead](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-type-ahead-widget), [another version](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead)

You will also need to create a controller action that this widget will use for searching. Here is a good example (for Select2):

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-ajax

Comment: Thanks for idea. I try all, but doesn't work, to many data. Typeahead work but is only to singledimension array, so search surname but don't return surname id? How to use typeahead with multidimension array?

Comment: I'm sorry, here's the right link: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-ajax.

Comment: Tjanks for this link. It is solution for me